# Why is bme/bmp280 temperature and humidity sensor returning 0 value?

Tags: pi-2, sensor

I'm having problems with `bme/bmp280`
 temperature and humidity sensor on my raspberry pi 2.
It does not give me feed back information. i have my ARM i2c protocols on and i wired it correctly but it still gives no readings (check attached pictures).

The library im usin i downloaded from 
here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_BMP280#usage-example

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Comment: Have you changed the `bmp280 = adafruit_bmp280.Adafruit_BMP280_I2C(i2c)` line in your code to use `address=0x76` the default in the Adafruit code is 0x77.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

Try my [example Python code](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_BME280_py).

Unzip the file which will create a file called BME280.py in the directory.

To run enter the following commands

```
sudo pigpiod # start the pigpio daemon

./BME280.py # reads for 60 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance for solving this problem that I have, this is much appreciated... However now I got this error, what do you think is wrong now? https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE5Ch.jpg

Comment: Based on that I'd say you have a poor or loose I2C connection.  Clear photos of the connections between the Pi and the sensor may help.